# Can destruction of the black hole restore original timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-2009

Nero travelled back in time which created a new timeline (*Star Trek* 2009 movie). The same thing happened when Vosk travelled back in time (*Star Trek: Enterprise* season 4).

When time machine of Vosk was destroyed by Enterprise NX-01, the original timeline was restored. Similarly, by destroying the black hole (using which Nero came to 23rd century), can original timeline be restored?

Comment: Iff the writers want it to.

Comment: The only reason they would destroy the black hole (or wormhole, or whatever) would be because Nero came back. If they destroy the black hole then Nero can't come back, so they don't know to destroy the wormhole, so the wormhole exists, so Nero comes back, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @Simon Looks like you don't understand the question. Its not a situation of paradox at all.

Comment: I think this would only work if they went back in time and stopped J.J. Abrams.

Comment: @DarthWedgius Here's hoping that someday J.J. Abrams' replacement will "not be a fan" of his work and will retroactively de-canonize the new timeline, whether a la Disney (with Star Wars) or by restoring the original timeline as suggested by this question.

Comment: How the hell do you destroy a black hole?

Answer (score 11):

**No, because the 2009 Timeline is not an alternate timeline from the perspective of the viewers (us). The previous timeline still exists (and if anyone cared to make movies, or television series there) the only difference would be Spock, as we know him is listed as missing or dead.**

This new timeline is simply a timeline where we are viewing this new Federation rather than the old one. A convenient way of allowing the franchise to go backward in time (with new faces but old names) and start all over again. They don't have to do any heavy lifting with selling people on a working franchise, only on dealing with new faces.

Answer (score 5):

I'd have to watch it again, but I thought Nero's (and, later, Spock's) ship came through a wormhole, which was a temporary phenomenon; there's nothing to destroy.  Said wormhole was technobabbled into existence by Spock and his magic <strike>Rambaldi</strike> red matter device.

It's not clear to me whether this new timeline *replaces* the old one; I think the intent is that this universe exists in parallel to the "original" universe, like the goatee universe from TOS and ENT or the multiple parallel universes Worf passed through in TNG.

Comment: Yeah, I think I remember that the wormhole they fell through was created by Spock stopping the Romulan nova, but too late to save the planet...